# Remove duplicate phrases in a foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, duplicates, explode

I have the following problem:

In my Wordpress 3.6 I have for posts a custom field called: "topics".
The field is automatically filled with phrases from another website by RSS, and it adds multiple criteria. It is filled in like this: "Cars,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget"

When I query wordpress with get_posts I get in my foreach loop this:

```
Cars,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget
Cars,Bikes
Bikes,Stuff
Gadget
```

I put this into a string and replace some stuff:

```
$topic_filter = get_posts(
 array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'private',
 )
);
$search_topic = array(' ', '-&-', '-|-', '-/-', '---');
$replace_topic = array("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "");

foreach ($topic_filter as $post_topic) {
$str = str_replace($search_topic, $replace_topic, get_post_meta($post_topic->ID,     'topic', true));

echo $str;

}
```

final echo putput is then:

```
Cars,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget,Cars,Bikes,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget
```

So far so good. But how to remove the duplicates now?

I tried implode / explode, but it doesn't do anything, because the items are in a foreach loop I think, and it only apply inside for each post.

But I need the foreach loop, because in the end the goal is to get this cleaned string as a list in an html output something like this:

```
<input
  type="button"
  value="Cars"
  class="filter-button"

  data-control-type="button-filter"
  data-control-action="filter"
  data-control-name="Cars-btn" 
  data-path=".Cars" 
/>
<input
  type="button"
  value="Bikes"
  class="filter-button"

  data-control-type="button-filter"
  data-control-action="filter"
  data-control-name="Bikes-btn" 
  data-path=".Bikes" 
/>
<input
  type="button"
  value="Gadget"
  class="filter-button"

  data-control-type="button-filter"
  data-control-action="filter"
  data-control-name="Gadget-btn" 
  data-path=".Gadget" 
/>
```

seems pretty complicated to me :-(

any ideas? I would be really happy for your help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique):

```
$str = "Cars,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget,Cars,Bikes,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget";
$r = explode(",", $str);
$unique = array_unique($r);
$new_str = implode(",", $unique);
```

Comment: Thank you, but array_unique also didn't work, I still get a list with all duplicates from wordpress:
    "Cars,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget,Cars,Bikes,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget"

Perhaps getting the result out of the foreach and than after editing back in?

Seems that he still works just per post, not global.

Comment: it seems the problem is that when using the first step 

    $r = explode(",", $str);

fails, because when I just echo this, it outputs:

    Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, ...

This seems not to work right, or?

Is there an alternative way to explode?

Comment: Huh .. are you sure `$str` is what you think it is? Can you do a `var_dump` (rather than `echo`)?

Comment: Ok I found my first error: I did not initialize the array first. But now I have every post_field in an array:
Array
(
    [0] => Cars,Bikes,Stuff,Gadget
    [1] => Cars,Bikes
    [2] => Bikes,Stuff
). It is accomplished by this code: $items = array();
foreach ($topic_filter as $post_topic) {
$str = '' . str_replace($search_topic, $replace_topic, get_post_meta($post_topic->ID, 'topic', true)) . '';
$items[] = $str;
}
print_r($items); ...So I need to extract the final String from the foreach loop first, than your first code will work, or am I wrong? :)

Comment: ok var_dump got me a bit further on. Now I have a clean $string with everything ripped of outside the loop. But when I try to convert it into an array, only var_dump works and gives me strange result: array(41) { [0]=> string(18) "Gadget" [1]=> string(23) "Car" [2]=> string(4) "Bikes" ...how may I put this into an HTML output?